# sorting and searching of data in table not working

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, sorting, search

I follow the tutorials on sorting and searching from:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

When I try to do this , sorting is not working. I want sorting on 3 fields, *username*, *user_role* and *date_of_register*. My **displayed data is not sorting in any order (just displaying the data)**.
Please can anyone help me what am I doing wrong.

```
//controller code:
    public ActionResult DisplayUsers(string sortOrder, string searchString)
        {
            ViewBag.NameSortParm1 = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";
            ViewBag.NameSortParm2 = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "role_desc" : "";
            ViewBag.DateSortParm = sortOrder == "Date" ? "date_desc" : "Date";

            var users = from a in db.app_user
                            select a;
          
            switch (sortOrder)
            {
                case "name_desc":
                    users = users.OrderByDescending(a => a.username);
                    break;
                case "role_desc":
                    users = users.OrderBy(a => a.user_role);
                    break;
                case "date_desc":
                    users = users.OrderBy(a => a.date_of_register);
                    break;
                default:
                    users = users.OrderBy(a => a.username);
                    break;
            }

            return View(db.app_user.ToList());
        }
```

View page

```
//DisplayUsers.cshtml page
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.ActionLink("User Name", "DisplayUsers", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm1 })
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.ActionLink("User Role", "DisplayUsers", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm2 })
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.is_active)                
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Enrollment Date", "DisplayUsers", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.DateSortParm })
                </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.username)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.user_role)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.is_active)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.date_of_register)
                </td>            
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
```

When I did: `return View(users.ToList());`
**Sorting is only based on field User Name but not no User Role and Enrollment Date. I can not sort the data on the basis of User Role or Enrollment Date** Why is it so?

**For searching:**
I tried searcing on username and date_of_register field. When I tried the code:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        users = users.Where(a => a.username.Contains(searchString) || a.date_of_register.Contains(searchString));
    }
```

getting the error:

> Error 1   Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.DateTime?' to
> 'System.Linq.IQueryable'
>
> Error 2   'System.DateTime?' does not contain a definition for
> 'Contains' and the best extension method overload
> 'System.Linq.Queryable.Contains(System.Linq.IQueryable,
> TSource)' has some invalid arguments

**How can I make search on date field**?
Please help me with this, any help on these will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I think you should return `users.ToList()`, instead you are returning the original unordered collection: `return View(db.app_user.ToList());` This is the reason why you are getting unordered data.

Comment: Thank you guys. I can do sorting on User Name and User Role. But can not sort on **Enrollment Date**. Why is it so?

Comment: Because `Contains` is a method which can be applied on String objects but in your case Enrollment Date is of type `DateTime`, so you need to compare it using `>= <=` instead.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44416992/iqueryable-convert-int-to-string-sortorder-and-filtring?noredirect=1#comment75840847_44416992 Having same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Sorting:

The problem is you're using a prefetched list but you're not sending it to view.

```
return View(db.app_user.ToList());
```

should be

```
return View(user.ToList());
```

> Searching:

You're again using Contains which expects the object is queryable while datetime is not, so you need to write a special case for datetime filter:

```
DateTime datetime = Convert.ToDateTime(searchString);
if (datetime.TimeOfDay != TimeSpan.Zero) //comparison with 00:00:00 time
{
    filterresults = filterresults.Where(x => x.TimeStarted == datetime);
}
else
{
    DateTime plusOneDateTime = datetime.AddDays(1).Date;
    filterresults = filterresults.Where(x => x.TimeStarted >= datetime.Date 
                                           && x.TimeStarted < plusOneDateTime);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not returning the users variable. fixed it below

```
public ActionResult DisplayUsers(string sortOrder, string searchString)
{
    ViewBag.NameSortParm1 = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";
    ViewBag.NameSortParm2 = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "role_desc" : "";
    ViewBag.DateSortParm = sortOrder == "Date" ? "date_desc" : "Date";

    var users = from a in db.app_user
                select a;

    switch (sortOrder)
    {
        case "name_desc":
            users = users.OrderByDescending(a => a.username);
            break;
        case "role_desc":
            users = users.OrderBy(a => a.user_role);
            break;
        case "date_desc":
            users = users.OrderBy(a => a.date_of_register);
            break;
        default:
            users = users.OrderBy(a => a.username);
            break;
    }

    return this.View(users.ToList());
    // return View(db.app_user.ToList());
}
```

As for part 2 of your question...

`date_of_register` is of type `DateTime?`, a nullable DateTime type does not contain a method named `Contains`, nor would it make sense for it to... if you want to check if the string is of type DateTime, you could try parsing it by using the following code...

```
if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchString))
{
    DateTime dateOfRegistration;

    bool isDateTime = DateTime.TryParse(searchString, out dateOfRegistration);
    if (isDateTime)
    {   
        users = users.Where(user => user.date_of_register == dateOfRegistration);
    }
    else 
    {
        users = users.Where(a => a.username.Contains(searchString));
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot do sorting on the field User Role and Enrollment Date. Why ?? Please can you guide me.

Comment: getting error on **else** block  `users = users.Where(a => a.username.Contains(searchString) || a.date_of_register == (searchString));
    }` **operator == cannot be applied on operands of type 'System.DateTime?' and 'string'**